# definition of a register in the .h file

Tags: macros, microcontroller

I try to understand the MKZW01Z4 microcontroller. When I look at the MKZW01Z4.h file, I see the macro definition :

```
* GPIO - Register instance definitions */
/* GPIOA */
#define GPIOA_PDOR                               GPIO_PDOR_REG(GPIOA)
#define GPIOA_PSOR                               GPIO_PSOR_REG(GPIOA)
#define GPIOA_PCOR                               GPIO_PCOR_REG(GPIOA)
#define GPIOA_PTOR                               GPIO_PTOR_REG(GPIOA)
#define GPIOA_PDIR                               GPIO_PDIR_REG(GPIOA)
#define GPIOA_PDDR                               GPIO_PDDR_REG(GPIOA)
```

As I understand it, this is to give a name to the port D registers. But actually, I would have expected that they give a name to an adress in the memory which correspond to the register, like :

```
#define GPIOA_PDOR                               0xE2C3
```

Indeed why would GPIO_PDOR_REG(GPIOA) be more clear to the compiler than GPIOA_PDOR?

Comment: Compilers do not have problems with "clarity". Probably the macro GPIO_PDOR_REG expands to something which, in the end, will assign 0xE2C3 to GPIO_PDOR. About why the header is made like this, I don't know; but who wrote it, probably knows why.

Comment: GPIO_PDOR_REG() is yet another macro, as is GPIOA.  So as linuxfan notes, if you drill down all the way to the bottom of the macros you will eventually find a concrete address.

Answer (score 1):

You do not try to understand the uC, you try to understand the macros. I guess that GPIOx registers have same offset from the GPIOx base address. So probably those macros just add this offset to the base address and they are universal eg if you change GPIOA to GPIOB as the macro argument you will get the register addresses of the GPIOB port instead. For programmers convenience author of the .h file has added GPIOx_xxxR definitions as well.